# Preprocessor directive #ifndef for C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, c-preprocessor

In eclipse, whenever I create a new C++ class, or **C** header file, I get the following type of structure.  Say I create header file example.h, I get this:

```
/*Comments*/
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H_
#define EXAMPLE_H_
/* Place to put all of my definitions etc. */
#endif
```

I think ifndef is saying that if EXAMPLE_H_ isn't defined, define it, which may be useful depending on what tool you are using to compile and link your project.  However, I have two questions:

1. Is this fairly common?  I don't see it too often.  And is it a good idea to use that rubric, or should you just jump right into defining your code.
2. What is EXAMPLE_H_ exactly?  Why not example.h, or just example?  Is there anything special about that, or could is just be an artifact of how eclipse prefers to auto-build projects?

Comment: Note that EVERYTHING goes in between the ifndef and the endif, in any case you as an application programmer are likely to experience.  So it's not just that the #define is being defined and included once, it's that everything is only being defined and included once.

Comment: Good point, sorry for not making that more clear, thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a common construct. The intent is to include the contents of the header file in the translation unit only once, even if the physical header file is included more than once. This can happen, for example, if you include the header directly in your source file, and it's also indirectly included via another header.

Putting the #ifndef wrapper around the contents means the compiler only parses the header's contents once, and avoids redefinition errors.

Some compilers allow "#pragma once" to do the same thing, but the #ifndef construct works everywhere.

Comment: Ah, okay, so you the #define statement is just there to define something, I could replace EXAMPLE_H_ to FOO_BAR_ in both cases, and it would still work, it's just better to use EXAMPLE_H_ as it is much less likely to have a namespace clash than if I were to give it any other name, yes?

Comment: Right, typically people use the name of the header with underscores for the characters which aren't valid in an identifier. Using a common name that could clash defeats the purpose :)

Comment: @Leif Andersen: Common names like example are likely to clash. Personally I prefix the file name with the full namespace as this is less likely to clash. I have seen other people generate full GUIDs to avoid the possibility of a clash.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a common way to protect your includes - in this way it prevents the code from being included twice. And the identifier used could be anything, it's just convention to do it the way described.

Answer (score 4):

Is it common? Yes - *all* C and C++ header files should be structured like this. EXAMPLE_H is a header guard, it prevents the code in the header being included more than once in the same translation unit, which would result in multiple definition errors. The name EXAPMLE_H is chosen to match the name of the header file it is guarding - it needs to be unique in your project and maybe globally as well. To try to ensure this, it's normal to prefix or suffix it with your project name:

```
#define MYPROJ_EXAMPLE_H
```

for example, if your project is called "myproj". Don't be tempted into thinking that prefixing with underscores will magically make it unique, by the way - names like `_EXAMPLE_H_` and `__EXAMPLE_H__` are illegal as they are reserved for the language implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Always do this at the top of a header file. It's typically called a header guard or an include guard.

What it does is make it so that if a header file would be included multiple times, it will only be included once. If you don't do it, then you'll end up with errors about things being defined multiple times and things like that.

The exact define doesn't matter that much, though typically it's some variation on the file name. Basically, you're checking whether the given macro has been defined. If it hasn't, then define it, and continue with including the file. If it has, then you must have included the file previously, and the rest of the file is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This is an include guard.  It guarantees that a header is included no more than once.

For example,  if you were to:

```
#include "example.h"
#include "example.h"
```

The first time the header is included, `EXAMPLE_H_` would not be defined and the if-block would be entered.  `EXAMPLE_H_` is then defined by the `#define` directive, and the contents of the header are evaluated.

The second time the header is included, `EXAMPLE_H_` is already defined, so the if-block is not re-entered.

This is essential to help ensure that you do not violate the one definition rule.  If you define a class in a header that didn't have include guards and included that header twice, you would get compilation errors due to violating the one definition rule (the class would be defined twice).

While the example above is trivial and you can easily see that you include `example.h` twice, frequently headers include other headers and it's not so obvious.

Comment: No it doesn't! It guarantees that it is included NO MORE THAN once :-)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this

File foo.c:

```
#include foo.h
#include bar.h
```

File bar.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include foo.h
```

Now, when we compile foo.c, we have foo.h in there twice! We definitely don't want this, because all the functions will throw compile errors the second time around.

To prevent this, we put the `INCLUDE GUARD` at the top. That way, if it's already been included, we define a preprocessor variable to tell us not to include it again.

It's very common (often mandated), and very frustrating if someone doesn't put one in there. You `should` be able to simply expect that each .h file has a header guard when you included. Of course, you know what they say when you assume things ("makes an ass of u and me") but that should be something you're expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an `include guard` and is indeed a common idiom for C/C++ header files. This allows the header file to be included multiple times without multiply including its contents.

The name `EXAMPLE_H_` is an arbitrary convention but has to obey naming rules for C preprocessor macros, which excludes names like `example.h`. Since C macros are all defined in a single global namespace, it is important that you do not have different header files that use the same name for their include guard. Therefore, it is usually a good idea to include the name of your project or library in the include guard name:

```
#ifndef __MYPROJECT_EXAMPLE_H__
...
```

Comment: Except that names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter or another underscore are reserved to the implementation (i.e., don't start your include guard names with an underscore).

Comment: @James and also any identifier containing two underscores in a row (i.e. not just at the beginning).  In other words, this answer is full of violations.  ;)