# XCode / New File / Header File --> default implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In XCode 8, when I add a new iOS header file to my project, it comes with this code already in it.

```
#ifndef SomeCoolWidget_h
#define SomeCoolWidget_h

#endif /* SomeCoolWidget */
```

Is there a good reason I shouldn't delete those directives and just do the usual ...

```
@interface SomeCoolWidget
...
@end
```

I have never left those compiler directives in our code and it has never caused a problem, but if there's no issue, I'm then left to wonder why that template is the default for every new header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@interface SomeCoolWidget...` is a "Cocoa Touch Class". There is an extra template for it and it creates a `Class.h` and `Class.m` file:

[image]

For a pure C header file, you do want the preprocessor directives. You can find some background why in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812248/1457385).

Answer (score 1):

Those are called `macro guards` basically preprocessor is checking that if `SomeCoolWidget` is included in your project before, if it is included it is returning a blank header file.

Another idea is when you have a bunch of related header files you want to prevent recursion.

Let's say A.h -> includes B.h and then B.h -> includes A.h , you dont want that in your code...

Finally let's say you have a `Play.h` and a `Record.h` , you can put them in your `SomeCoolWidget` header then use  SomeCoolWidget header to both play and record in some other class.

```
#import "Play.h"
#import "Record.h"
```

So `@interface SomeCoolWidget` usage is different then SomeCoolWidget.h usage. You need to choose whatever suits your needs

Comment: But doesn't `#import` automagically prevent recursion.  Wasn't that the purpose of using it instead of `#include`

Comment: No it doesn't , to me it is just a way of helping to organize my code and write clean code. If you wanna break your code by recursive importing,  it is not gonna stop you.

Comment: you can check this thread for further info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files

Comment: u.gen   -- That's not what tons of people say here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c    It specifically says that `#imports` prevents recursion.